# What does the for loop do in the following code?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to learn scikit learn (sklearn). Following is a part of code trying to create a data frame with statsmodels.api from iris dataset. 
But I'm not sure how the for loop works and the datatypes of `iris.target_names[x]` & `target` from sci-kit. Can anyone please explain?

```
from sklearn import datasets ## Get dataset from sklearn

## Import the dataset from sklearn.datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()

## Create a data frame from the dictionary
species = [iris.target_names[x] for x in iris.target]
```

Comment: It is a list comprehension: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is list comprehension and it do

```
species = []

for x in iris.target:
    val = iris.target_names[x]
    species.append(val)
```

`for` gets values one-by-one from column `iris.target`and assigns to `x` and then it use this `x` to get value from column `iris.target_names` and appends this value on list `species.

So it converts values `target` to values `target_name`

Answer (score 2):

This is functionally equivalent to the following:

```
species = []
for x in iris.target:
    species.append(iris.target_names[x])
```

In essence it is applying a function on every element x in the iterable and creating a list out of the results.

Performing an operation over a list this way is slightly faster than the previously mentioned method and is more readable (in my opinion).